# XAMPP Unable to load dynamic library (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: php, makefile, xampp, php-cpp

I am using XAMPP for my PHP project to run it locally. It utilizes PHP extensions written with PHP-CPP library.

I am having this error when I check for my `/opt/lampp/bin/php -m`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'module_name.so' (tried: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/module_name.so (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib/libphpcpp.so.2.4)),
```

This is part of my Makefile:

```
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic  -I/opt/lampp/include/ -o
LINKER_FLAGS        =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp
```

When I look for CXXABI in my local system i can find it:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_1.3.10
CXXABI_1.3.11
CXXABI_1.3.12
CXXABI_1.3.13
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_FLOAT128
```

But i can not find the version in the folder i believe XAMPP utilize:

```
$ strings /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_TM_1
```

when i checked:
`ldd /lib/libphpcpp.so.2.4`

i got

```
$ ldd /lib/libphpcpp.so.2.4
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe22142000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffaab200000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffaab4e2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffaaae00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffaab5c8000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffaab119000)
```

how can i update this library inside of XAMPP or is there any other way to solve this.